# Echo values of arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, echo

I want to echo the values of all arrays that has been returned from a search function. Each array contains one `$category`, that have been gathered from my DB. The code that I've written so far to `echo` these as their original value (e.g. in the same form they lay in my DB.) is:

```
$rows = search($rows);

if (count($rows) > 0) {
    foreach($rows as $row => $texts) {
        foreach ($texts as $idea) {
            echo $idea; 
        }
    }
}
```

However, the only thing this code echoes is a long string of all the info that exists in my DB.

The function, which result I'm calling looks like this:

```
function search($query) {

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace("[^A-Za-zÅÄÖåäö0-9 -_.]", "", $query));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE categories LIKE '%$query%'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $rows = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows['text'] = $row;
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);

    return $rows;
}
```

How can I make it echo the actual text that should be the value of the array?

Comment: you need to include what `function search` does

Comment: You seem to have an array of arrays - do a `print_r($rows)` to see the structure.

Comment: Add `print_r($rows);` before your `foreach` and post the output.

Comment: I understand that I've screwed something up, since a var_dump($rows) looks like this: array(0) { } Would you mind taking a look at my code, and maby help me determine what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `echo $rows['categories'] = $row;` inside your while loop is the big problem. You probably want `$rows[$categories][] = $row` instead.

Comment: But $categories is undefined? And what would I echo?

Comment: @NorS You shouldn't be echoing anything from within the search function. Its purpose would appear to be to collect and return results, not display them. `echo` is for sending things to the browser. Using `$rows['categories'][]` appends rows to the array rather than overwriting the array each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line: `echo $rows['categories'] = $row;` in your search function is problematic. For every pass in your `while` loop, you are storing all rows with the same key. The effect is only successfully storing the last row from your returned query.

You should change this...

```
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $rows['categories'] = $row;
}

mysql_free_result($result);

return $rows;
```

to this...

```
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

return $rows;
```

Then when you are accessing the returned value, you could handle it like the following...

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $array) {
    echo $array['columnName'];
    // or
    foreach ($array as $column => $value) {
        echo $column; // column name
        echo $value; // stored value
    }
}
```

Comment: Let PHP auto index the array for you. Instead of `echo $rows['categories'] = $row;`, use `$rows[] = $row;`. This will store each row with a numeric key beginning with zero. When you use the returned value in your `foreach` loop, you can access the values by key like `$categories['columnName']`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'columnName', do you have an example of a possible value?

Comment: I just mean the column name as you have it stored in your database.

Comment: I've made some revisions to my answer above. Let me know if that clears up what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Should anything be inserted between the square brackets in "$row[]"?

Comment: No. Leaving it empty will cause PHP to automatically index each row with a unique numeric value beginning with zero.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to work. It's probably something else that's messed up with my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3066/discussion-between-65fbef05-and-nors)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a multi-dimensional array, that is each element of your array is another array.

Instead of

```
echo $row['categories'];
```

try [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
print_r($row['categories']);
```

This will technically do what you ask, but more importantly, it will help you understand the structure of your sub-arrays, so you can print the specific indices you want instead of dumping the entire array to the screen.

Comment: My print_r($row), shows me that my arrays have a value of 0. Do you think you could overlook the code for my function search()?

Answer (score 1):

What does a `var_dump($rows)` look like? Sounds like it's a multidimensional array. You may need to have two (or more) loops:

```
foreach($rows as $row => $categories) {
   foreach($categories as $category) {
      echo $category;
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand that I've screwed something up, since a var_dump($rows) looks like this: array(0) { }

Would you mind taking a look at my code, and maby help me determine what I'm  doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
foreach ($rows as $row => $categories) {
    echo $categories;
}
```

If this will output a sequence of Array's again, try to see what in it:

```
foreach ($rows as $row => $categories) {
    print_r($categories);
}
```